# What is the best way to initialize the following instance in my class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Consider the following class where I am overwriting the `OutputStream`

```
public class MyOutputStream extends java.io.OutputStream {
    public String clientId = null;
    public String fileId = null;
    public String filelocation = null;
    public DBClient clientobj = null;
    public OuputStream out = null;

    public MyOuputStream(String clientid, String fileid, String filelocation) {
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.fileid = fileid;
        this.filelocation = filelocation;
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        out.write(bytes);
    }

    private DBClient getInstance(String clientid, String fileid) throws DBClientException {
        return this.clientobj = DBClient.getInstance(clientid, fileid);
    }

    private OutputStream getOuputStream(DFSClient clientobj) throws Exception {
        return this.out = clientobj.getOutputStream();
    }
}
```

> In the above code to write using `MyOuputStream` the DBClient object and OuputStream has to be initialized before write operation

Someone, please suggest me an appropriate design pattern to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're extending `java.io.OutputStream` to begin with if you're going to just create another `OutputStream` field and use its instance methods. As for your question, anything which must be initialized prior to calling instance methods should be included in the object's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `MyOutputStream` to forward all output to the `OutputStream` retrieved from the `DBClient` object, you want to extend `FilterOutputStream`, so you get all the delegate implementations for free.

To use it, you must give the `OutputStream` from `DBClient` to the `FilterOutputStream` constructor, so you need to prepare the data in a static method.

```
public class MyOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private String clientId;
    private String fileId;
    private String fileLocation;
    private DBClient clientobj;

    public static MyOutputStream create(String clientId, String fileId, String fileLocation) {
        DBClient clientobj = DBClient.getInstance(clientId, fileId);
        return new MyOutputStream(clientId, fileId, fileLocation, clientobj);
    }

    private MyOutputStream(String clientId, String fileId, String fileLocation, DBClient clientobj) {
        super(clientobj.getOutputStream());
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
        this.clientobj = clientobj;
    }

}
```

Now, instead of writing `new MyOuputStream(clientId, fileId, fileLocation)`, you write `MyOuputStream.create(clientId, fileId, fileLocation)`.